# Is there any way to unmerge meshes such as toes after remeshing?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting, sculpt, remesh

So, after remeshing to 0.01, for my human body, my toes ended up merging. When I tried to use the lasso trim tool to separate them, it just freezes my program and I'm forced to close down my program and reopen it. Is there any way to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest before applying the remesh modifier, separate the toes to different meshes such that each one has the remesh modifier. Then add boolean union to the body with all the toes. I used "Fast" boolean to make things easier. This works okayish, you can then smooth and tweak the intersecting areas for finer results.